# Creatable in React-Select and Typescript fails with error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-select

I'm creating a React app and using `react-select`. I'm trying to use the Creatable part but when I import it I am getting an error.

I installed both `react-select` and `@types/react-select`

```
npm install --save react-select
npm install --save-dev @types/react-select
```

when I import like the docs say

```
import Creatable from 'react-select/creatable';
```

I get this type error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-select/creatable'. '/path/to/app/node_modules/react-select/creatable/dist/react-select.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016)
```

I even tried importing it like this

```
import { Creatable } from 'react-select';
```

but I got this error

```
Attempted import error: 'Creatable' is not exported from 'react-select'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';

export default class App extends Component {

  options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
  ];

  render() {

    return(
      <CreatableSelect
        isClearable
        options={this.options}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Tenusha, I'm not trying to use the default Select from React-Select. What you have there I already have working.   I'm trying to use this https://react-select.com/creatable

Comment: @user1184205 answer updated. If that doesn't work, then there is no problem with the code. Try reinstalling the package. My version is `"react-select": "^3.0.4"`

Comment: remove the current `react-select` dependency and run `npm install` (that will remove it from `node_modules` as well). Then run `npm install react-select`

Comment: thanks for the reply but I uninstalled both `react-select` & `@types/react-select` and reinstalled them and getting the same error. " Could not find a declaration file for module `'react-select/creatable'`."  I have `"react-select": "^3.0.4"` & `"@types/react-select": "^2.0.19"`.

Comment: It doesn't look as though the type definitions have been updated for 3.0.0 yet. There's a [PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/36464) in at the moment for the updated definitions.

Comment: your right @Dairylee, thanks. I can't believe I didn't catch that.